# Erlang filter list using lists:keyfind partial string

Tags: erlang

I am almost new with `Erlang`

I have a list as:

```
List = [[{name, <<"redCar1">>}, {turbo, true}], [{name, <<"redCar2">>}, {turbo, true}], [{name, <<"greenCard">>}, {turbo, false}]].
```

Now I want to filter all `"red"` Cars

I tried using:

```
filterCar() ->
  MyF = fun(List) ->
    case lists:keyfind(name, 1, List) of
      {name, <<"red", _Rest/binary>>} ->
        true:
      _ ->
        false
    end
  end,
  MyF.
```

Then

```
lists:filter(MyF, List),
```

It works perfectly.

Now I want to create an generic function to filter, like:

```
myfilter(Value, List) ->
  case lists:keyfind(name, 1, List) of
    {name, <<Value, _Rest/binary>>} ->
      true;
    _ ->
      false
  end.
```

But when I try to execute this function I got always `[]` empty list.

I am sure the problem is when I try to pass `Value` because if I replace

```
 {name, <<Value, _Rest/binary>>}
```

with

```
{name, <<"red", _Rest/binary>>}
```

It works.

My aim it to find all string that start with `car` in ignore case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to indicate two more things to use a general value in your binary: that it's a binary, and the size of that binary.

```
filterCar(Value) when is_binary(Value) ->
    MyF = fun(List) ->
                  Size = byte_size(Value),
                  case lists:keyfind(name, 1, List) of
                      {name, <<Value:Size/binary, _Rest/binary>>} ->
                          true;
                      _ ->
                          false
                  end
          end,
    MyF.
```

First we changed `filterGuard` to take one argument, `Value`, which is the pattern we want to look for. We use a guard on the function to ensure `Value` is a binary. Inside the internal `fun` we first retrieve the size of `Value` via `byte_size/1`, which we need so that we can set the expected field size in the matching binary. This leads to the key change, which is `<<Value:Size/binary, _Rest/binary>>`: we set the expected size of the `Value` field, and we define it as a `binary` field.

With this change in place, we can successfully apply it to your `List` variable, passing `<<"red">>` for `Value`:

```
1> lists:filter(filterCar(<<"red">>), List).
[[{name,<<"redCar1">>},{turbo,true}],
 [{name,<<"redCar2">>},{turbo,true}]]
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But suppose the list is like this `{name, "redCar1"}`. is it the same? I'm trying without using binary `<<>>`  without success.

Comment: If you want to also be able to pass a string as a key, change the last line from `MyF.` to `MyF;` then add another function clause: `filterCar(Value) when is_list(Value) -> filterCar(list_to_binary(Value)).`